# How to change logon enable/disable remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When change mode of logons on Terminal Servers to **Disable**. I frequently forget to reenable it before I close my session.
obviously I can not reconnect to change if.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WMI **Win32_TerminalServiceSetting** to check and change the status of TSLogons

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_TerminalServiceSetting -N "root/cimv2/terminalservices" -computername $_ -Authentication PacketPrivacy
```

i write 2 function for enable and disable it on many computers simultanusly

```
function LogonDisable {
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
            [Alias("CN")]
                [string[]]$ComputerName
        )
    TRY {
        $ComputerName | Select-Object -Unique | %{
            $TS_Connector = Get-WmiObject Win32_TerminalServiceSetting -N "root/cimv2/terminalservices" -computername $_ -Authentication PacketPrivacy
            $TS_Connector.Logons=1
            $TS_Connector.Put()
            $TS_Connector.Get()
            if ($TS_Connector.Logons -eq 1) {
                "OK"
            } else {
                "Error"
            }
        }
    }#TRY
    CATCH {
        Write-Warning -Message "$($Error[0].Exception)"
    }
}

function LogonEnable {
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
            [Alias("CN")]
                [string[]]$ComputerName
        )
    TRY {
        $ComputerName | Select-Object -Unique | %{
            $TS_Connector = Get-WmiObject Win32_TerminalServiceSetting -N "root/cimv2/terminalservices" -computername $_ -Authentication PacketPrivacy
            $TS_Connector.Logons=0
            $TS_Connector.Put()
            $TS_Connector.Get()
            if ($TS_Connector.Logons -eq 0) {
                "OK"
            } else {
                "Error"
            }
        }
    }#TRY
    CATCH {
        Write-Warning -Message "$($Error[0].Exception)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ability to disable access to offline server

Logon mode for RDP is per-server configuration that is stored in registry. Configuration of logon mode is stored in registry in two different locations:

drainMode

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\TSServerDrainMode
0 = Allow all connections
1 = Allow reconnections, but prevent new logon until reboot
2 = Allow reconnections, but prevent new logon
```

logons

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\WinStationsDisabled
0 = Enabled
1 = Disabled
```

When server is in drain mode, WinStationDisabled is always 0 (enabled).